# hiding crosstab columns in BIRT when format is excel

Tags: birt

I want to hide two of the crosstab columns based on some condition. I have been able to achieve it by using

```
 function onPrepareCell( cell, reportContext )
 if(some condition){
    if( cell.getCellID() == cell#){
    cell.getStyle().setDisplay("none");
    }
  }
```

in the onPrepare event of cross tab. It works fine in PDF,HTML format but the columns are not getting hidden when the format is Excel. I need to get this done soon please help

Comment: Ideally i would like to make the width of the cell to 0 from the script but i am not able to get any method to do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer from BIRT exchange i am posting the answer here so that it may be helpful to others

In the onPrepare() event of crosstab you can write the code as given below

function onPrepareCrosstab( crosstab,  reportContext )
{
    if(some condition ){
        reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(ElementId#).setStringProperty("width","0px");
    }

}

here ElementId# is the Id# of the cell you want to hide. As you can see we can also use this to change the width of the cell dymanically.

Answer (score 0):

Try your code in an OnCreateCell event.