# Access data value of a cell at "onPrepareCell" event in Birt crosstab

Tags: birt

I got know how to hide crosstab column in Excel Birt export at "onprepare" event of crosstab or cell [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781260/hiding-crosstab-columns-in-birt-when-format-is-excel).

My question is how to access data value of a cell at "onPrepareCell" event so for example if value ="EURO" set width of this cell to 0 as something like as below:

```
function onPrepareCell( cell, reportContext )
 if(cell.getReport.getDataItem("CURRENCY") == "EURO" ){
    if( cell.getCellID() == cell#){
    reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(ElementId#).setStringProperty("width","0px");
    } 
}
```

but I can't extract value from IDataItem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

We can't access dataItem in
**onPrepareCell( cell, reportContext )**

Instead use the Report parameter from outside of crosstab

```
onPrepareCell(cell, reportContext){
    if (reportContext.getParameterValue("CURRENCY") == "EURO") {
        if (cell.getCellID() == cell#){
            reportContext.getDesignHandle().getElementByID(ElementId#).setStringProperty("width", "0px");
        }
    }
}
```